# How to justify my solution of this problem, even though I got the right answer?!

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem that I would like to justify the solution of, even though I somehow got the right answer?!

**Problem:** Let $u=(2,1,1)^t, v=(1,0,1)^t, u'=(1,1,0)^t, v'=(6,3,3)^t$, where $u,v,u',v'$ are column vectors, written as the transposes of row vectors to save space.

Let $B$ = $(u,v)$, $B'$ = $(u',v')$. $B$ and $B'$ are two different bases for the same 2-dimensional subspace $W$ of $R^3$.

(a) Find $P$ such that $B'=BP$.

(b) Find the coordinate vector of $u'$ with respect to $B$.

I got $P=\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$
and I got for part (b), the answer as $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$.

**My attempt:**

For part a, I solved for $P$ straight from the equation $B'=BP$, by creating a linear system in which $P$ is a $2$ x $2$ matrix.

For part b, I solved for $u'$ using the fact that $B[u']_{B}=u'$. Then, because B is a $3$ x $2$ matrix and $u'$ is a $3$ x $1$ matrix, $[u']_{B}$ is a $2$ x $1$ matrix. I solved this linear system directly.

What is the best way to go about solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you tell us how you got to the right answer?  Maybe your method was correct after all. (And in any case it is easiest for us to help you if you show your work on the problem.)